# 3 column grid on desktop, 2 column at 768px tablet

Tags: css

I am using a CSS grid inside of a CSS grid and I am having trouble getting two rows of three images to change into three rows of two images. It works in my browser when I resize the window, but not when I test in responsive design mode on an ipad width, even when set to landscape. I have tried using @media to set a specific breakpoint, but that doesn't seem to work either. Here is my grid and what I have tried so far:

```
/*Primary container*/
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: 3rem;
}

/*Secondary container*/
.section-grid-index {
  --auto-grid-min-size: 16rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--auto-grid-min-size), 1fr));
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 2rem;
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 10 / 9;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  section > article {
    display: block;
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  section > article {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
      section > article {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        width: 45%;
      }
    }

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .article {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

I tried the individual media queries one at a time. The best that I can get is a single column of 6 items, each 45% of their original size. I used 45% just in case I had some issue with the box model to see if that is what was throwing things off.